# How to replace a fixed number of chars from the beginning?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

I tried replacing 30 chars from the beginning of each line of my text, but could not figure out how to specify to `vi` `sed` to do it.

I tried this:

```
:%s/.{3}/xx/
```

But it could not find my pattern. I thought `{3}` would mean *3 times* the previous, but unfortunately not. `{` is not interpreted as a regex command but as a search char.

could anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at [`:h magic`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2Fmagic):

Examples:

```
after:    \v       \m       \M       \V         matches 
                'magic' 'nomagic'
          $        $        $        \$         matches end-of-line
          .        .        \.       \.         matches any character
          *        *        \*       \*         any number of the previous atom
          ~        ~        \~       \~         latest substitute string
          ()       \(\)     \(\)     \(\)       grouping into an atom
          |        \|       \|       \|         separating alternatives
          \a       \a       \a       \a         alphabetic character
          \\       \\       \\       \\         literal backslash
          \.       \.       .        .          literal dot
          \{       {        {        {          literal '{'
          a        a        a        a          literal 'a'
```

The default node in regular expressions is `\m` (just magic), so you need to use [`\{`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%7B) for the brace to seen as an operator:

```
                                        /\{ E58 E60 E554 E870
\{n,m}  Matches n to m of the preceding atom, as many as possible
\{n}    Matches n of the preceding atom
\{n,}   Matches at least n of the preceding atom, as many as possible
\{,m}   Matches 0 to m of the preceding atom, as many as possible
```

Try:

```
%s/.\{30}/xx/
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for me under `Linux` , but not `AIX`. btw nothig with `:h magic` on my systems.

Comment: under `AIX` it says `Invalid character in interval expression` ; but if I escape the second one, it works.

Answer (score 3):

In AIX `vi`, this will be:

```
:%s/.\{30\}/xx/
```